# Is there a better way to convert from decimal to binary in python?

Tags: python, binary

I need to convert from an integer to a list of size 8 that is the binary representation of that number (number <= 255) and back.  Currently I am using these lines

```
list(bin(my_num)[2:].rjust(8,'0'))
int("".join(my_list),2)
```

I did some googling, but had a hard time finding relevant information.  I'm just curious if there is a faster, or more standard way to do this.

**edit:**
Would using bit masking make it faster.  E.g. something like this

`[(my_num>>y)&1 for y in xrange(7,-1,-1)]`

Like I mentioned in a comment I am using this for a steganography app I am writing, so I am doing this thousands of times (3 times per pixel in an image), so speed is good.

Comment: This is like the fourth "how do I convert to binary" question we've had this week (mostly in different languages), what is **up**? Is this homework? (This is not criticism, I'm just amazed; converting numbers to binary representation just doesn't come up that much in general programming...)

Comment: I'd say no, but someone would probably correct me. I'm not sure if a >> loop would be faster than bin(), but you wouldn't need the rjust()

Comment: This is not homework.  I am working on a steganography app.  It's probably not the best way to do it, but it was the obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2.6 or newer, use `format` [syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
'{0:0=#10b}'.format(my_num)[2:]
# '00001010'
```

One of the neat things about Python strings is that they are sequences. If all you need to do is iterate through the characters, then there is no need to convert the string to a list.

**Edit**: For steganography, you might be interested in converting a stream of characters into a stream of bits. Here is how you could do that with generators:

```
def str2bits(astr):
    for char in astr:    
        n=ord(char)
        for bit in '{0:0=#10b}'.format(n)[2:]:
            yield int(bit)
```

And to convert a stream of bits back into a stream of characters:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    # Source: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    return itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n,fillvalue=fillvalue)

def bits2str(bits):
    for b in grouper(8,bits):
        yield chr(int(''.join(map(str,b)),2))
```

For example, you could use the above functions like this:

```
for b in str2bits('Hi Zvarberg'):
    print b,
# 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1

# To show bits2str is the inverse of str2bits:
print ''.join([c for c in bits2str(str2bits('Hi Zvarberg'))])
# Hi Zvarberg
```

Also, SO guru [Ned Batchelder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14343/ned-batchelder) does some steganography-related experiments using Python and PIL  [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200806/spore_creature_creator_and_steganography.html). You may be able to find some useful code there.

If you find you need more speed (and still want to code this in Python), you may want to look into using [numpy](https://numpy.org/).

Comment: Yes, but in order to change an element I need a list correct?  Strings are immutable.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to the Steganography stuff.  I try to avoid looking at other Steganography articles in python because I want this app to be my app.  I'm afraid if I look at other peoples solutions, their ideas will slip into my code without me finding my own solutions.  I have a working app and it works pretty well, I'm just trying to make some improvements.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`zfill`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) instead of `rjust`.

```
list(bin(my_num)[2:].zfill(8))
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed this function in my searching.

Comment: I tried using this line in my app replacing the bit masking solution I posted above, and it gave me an average improvement of about 20%.  zfill gave an improvement of about 2% on average over the rjust method as well, but an improvement of 12% in the worst case.  Of course all that data is for my specific app so I don't know if it's universal, but it's good enough for me!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method for decimal to binary conversion:

- divide the decimal number by 2
- take the remainder and record it in on the side
- divide the quotient by 2
- repeat until the decimal cannot be divided further
- record the remainder in reverse order and you get the resultant binary number

Which may be coded as:

```
d=int(raw_input("enter your decimal:"))
l=[]
while d>0:
    x=d%2
    l.append(x)
    d=d/2
l.reverse()
for i in l:
    print i,
print " is the decimal representation of givin binary data."
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting an answer. Please reformat your answer. As written, it appears as gibberish.

Comment: @RichardErickson  actually i m new so not getting how to post with right indentation

Comment: Thank you for formatting your answer. However, would you please explain your code rather than only posting code. While this code _may_ answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I have given here program for decimal to binary conversion.

```
print "Program for Decimal to Binary Conversion"

n = 0
bin = 0
pos = 1

print "Enter Decimal Number:", 
n = input()

while(n > 0):
   bin = bin + (n % 2) * pos;
   n = n / 2;
   pos *= 10;

print "The Binary Number is: ", bin       

#sample output
#Program for Decimal to Binary Conversion
#Enter Decimal Number: 10
#The Binary Number is: 1010
```

Answer (score 0):

**First solution**:
A fast method must not use loops.
I would recommend using a lookup table that you would build once and use as often you wish.

```
tb = []
for i in range(256):
  tb.append( f"{i:08b}")
# once build you can use it for the whole image.
print( tb[27]) # will print: 00011011
```

**Second solution**:
but if you're really serious about speed, you should not use characters. You should load your image in a bytearray (it is mutable) and directly modify bits in pixel.

```
img[2][8] |≃ 0b10 # set second bit from right
img[2][8] |= 1<<1 # same
img[2][8] &= ~0b10 # reset second bit
img[2][8] &= ~1<<1 # same
img[2][8] ^= 0b1010  # invert second and fourth bits
```